# Why is this a local isomorphism?(model theory)

Tags: logic

In Kees Doets's *Basic Model Theory*, **local isomorphism** is defined as follows:

> A local isomorphism between models A and B of the same vocabulary is a finite relation {${(a_1,b_1),...,(a_n,b_n)}$}⊆ $A×B$ such that the simple expansions $(A,a_1,...,a_n)$ and $(B,b_1,...,b_n)$ satisfy
> the same atomic sentences.

And then, it says:The finite injection {${(0,0),(2,e),(5,\pi)}$} is a local isomorphism between (Z,<) and (R,<).

My question is, what about this atomic sentence: 4<c,where c is to be substituted by 5 or $\pi$?
In A, c = 5, 4<5 is a true atomic sentence,
but in B, c=$\pi$, 4<$\pi$ is false.
How comes that {${(0,0),(2,e),(5,\pi)}$} is a local isomorphism between (Z,<) and (R,<)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the point here is that $4 < c$ cannot be expressed as an atomic sentence in the relevant expansions of $(Z, <)$ or $(R, <)$: with no constant symbols in the base language, and no ability to use quantifiers, there's no way to "name" any numbers in these expansions other than the ones specified by the local isomorphism (for which we are directly adding new constant symbols).